# Mustache. Проитерировать коллекцию объектов в .mustache

Tags: java, шаблонизаторы, mustache

если в `books` передать массив значений все работает:

```
<ul>
    {{#books}}
        <il>{{.}}</il>
    {{/books}}
</ul>
```

как переписать код, если `books` содержит несколько полей (название, описание)

**контроллер:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String main(Model model){

    List<Book> books = bookMapper.allBook();

    model.addAttribute("books",books);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тогда указавать названия полей

```
<ul>
    {{#books}}
        <li>{{name}} : {{description}}</li>
    {{/books}}
</ul>
```